# MS CRM 2013 Notes becoming readonly after removing title and Text

Tags: readonly, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any workaround to prevent Notes in MS CRM 2013 from becoming readonly when we remove the Title and text from it?

I would like it to be editable even after the title and text is removed from the Notes. Is it possible? Any help will be much appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dig up the record and edit it, just not in the parent form:

Advanced Find > search "Notes"

Filter by `Regarding` record (i.e. if the note is attached to a Case, pick `Regarding(Incident)`)

You'll see in the results your empty record: open it up and edit it.